# How to Display multiple images from db using MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to `MVC.`I have saved the image and some data but can't display the saved images. I want to display all saved images in the main page.

**Model:** Get the db list from model

```
public List<Products> GenreList()
        {
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult MYsample()
{
    var MyList = storeDB.GenreList();
    var a= MyList.Count;

    if (a != null)
    {
        foreach (var li in MyList)
        {
            return File(li.fileContent, li.mimeType,li.fileName);
        }
    }
    return View(MyList);
}
```

**View**

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
            <img src="@Url.Action("MYsample", "HomeController", new { id = item.ProductID })" alt="@item.Productname" />
    }
```

Comment: The problem is with the behavior of your code, return statement in for-loop will return first image as response and exit the function without hitting the view. BTW you could try what DarinDimitrov suggested +1 for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could start by writing a controller action that will serve the images to the response stream:

```
public ActionResult Image(int id)
{
    // you should add a method to your repository that returns the image 
    // record from the id
    Products image = storeDB.Get(id);
    return File(image.fileContent, image.mimeType);
}
```

and then in your main controller action send the list of images to the view:

```
public ActionResult MySample()
{
    var model = storeDB.GenreList();
    return View(model);
}
```

and then in your strongly typed view loop through the images and generate an `<img>` tag for each image by pointing its `src` property to the newly created controller action:

```
@model MyList
@foreach (var li in MyList)
{
    <img src="@Url.Action("Image", new { id = li.Id })" alt="" />
}
```

If you don't want to have a separate controller action that will query the database and retrieve the image record from an id you could use the [`data URI scheme`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). Bear in mind though that this is not supported by all browsers.

So the idea is that your controller action will send the image data to the view:

```
public ActionResult MySample()
{
    var model = storeDB.GenreList();
    return View(model);
}
```

and then inside your strongly typed view you could loop through the list and generate the proper `<img>` tag:

```
@model MyList
@foreach (var li in MyList)
{
    <img src="src="data:@(li.mimeType);base64,@(Html.Raw(Convert.ToBase64String(li.fileContent)))" alt="" />
}
```

Comment: why ToBase64String function is required to display image ?